# VSCode only search open files in a workspace ? [2020]

Tags: visual-studio-code

VSCode is suddenly only searching open files within a workspace. I'm using Remote ssh and Prettier and I have not changed any settings. Has anyone have any experience with this ? Ctrl+Shift+F does not seems to work.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/97107

Answer (score 5):

In my case i finded the problem in the .gitignore. I open the vs code in main directory. This main directory has a script to download the back-end and the front-end and has too a file .gitignore for ignore the the back-end and the front-end in commits. Because this the VSCode only search open files in a workspace.

More details in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Search-Issues#missing-search-results.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find what caused the problem but my fix was to delete and recreate the workspace, or just open the folder.